# Alamofire get response from POST

Tags: swift, post, alamofire

How can I get response from POST method using Alamofire?
I have next POST method:

```
let parameters = [
                  "Firstname":  "\(first_name)",
                  "Lastname": "\(last_name)",

                 ];
 Alamofire.request(.POST, URLString, parameters: parameters as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: .JSON)
```

And when this is done, I want to get a response my record with ID and other fields. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a method like this...

```
func getData(result: (response: NSMutableArray!, error : NSError!) -> Void){

let parameters = [
                  "Firstname":  "\(first_name)",
                  "Lastname": "\(last_name)", ];        

    //Request to fetch data from the server
    Alamofire.request(.POST,URLString, parameters: parameters,encoding:.JSON).responseJSON
       { response in switch response.result {
           case .Success(let jsonData):
                result(response: jsonData  as! NSMutableArray,  error: nil)
           case .Failure(let error):
                result(response: nil, error: error)
           }
       }

}//getData
```

And call above method as...

```
 YOURCLASSOBJECT.getFeedData( { (response, error) -> Void in

        //If data is fetched successfully
        if(response != nil){

          print("Response : \(response)")
        }  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, URLString, parameters:parameters,encoding:.JSON).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
        if response.result.value != nil {
             print(response.result.value)
        }
    }
```